# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency and QiuckTimePlugin

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, webview, ios5

In my app there is a modal view with web view added like this:

```
CustomController* newsView = [[CustomController alloc] initWithData:data delegate:self];
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsView];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
[nav release];
[newsView release];
```

In web view inside custom controller's view i have a link to video and it plays nice inside the web view but crashes on the fullscreen mode with UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exeption. Default plugin (QuickTime) is used to show video. I guess, it's about new view hierarchy in ios 5.0 but I still can't fix it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Found a similar thread with more attention but still no answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905258/ios5-exception-on-uiwebview-in-modal-uiviewcontroller-playing-youtube-video