# Youtube embedded in UIWebView causes crash on iPad when entering full screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, youtube, freeze

I'm trying to embed a Youtube video using a mixture of [this technique](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html), and [this Youtube SDK blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html) in a universal app. The iPhone version, using the same code, works fine.
On the iPad the video does embed, and it plays fine in it's embedded form, but as soon as you tap the full screen button the app crashes (buttons do not respond, the device does not rotate). The music from the Youtube video keeps playing.

There is no error message logged but the app does register as 'Paused' or hung in xCode. Every time it crashes com.apple.libdispatch-manager is on thread 2. Ask me questions and I'll give you more information about the error, but I'm not sure where to start.

I have tried:

- changing the size of the UIWebView frame
- the UIWebView is in a UIScrollView, but if I take it out of the scrollview and add it to the view the problem is identical.
- changing the video
- changing the html that I use in the UIWebView from [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html) to [this](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html), with no result
- changing the format of the youtube link from ?v=uniqueID to /v/uniqueID
- checking the presenting view is the rootviewcontroller (it is, but the video is embedded in a modal, which is not the rootviewcontroller).

I am building for iOS 5.1, **this doesn't happen if running on iOS6**.

The View that the video is embedded in is modal, both on the phone and the iPad. There's no hackery or unusual things happening in the app.

There seems to be talk of Evernote's app having a [similar problem](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/25878-bug-crashing-on-youtube-full-screen/), but I don't know if it is related or not.

For your reference, here is the YouTubeView subclass (which subclasses UIWebView):

```
- (YouTubeView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        // Create webview with requested frame size
        self = [[YouTubeView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

// HTML to embed YouTube video
//      NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>
//                                       <body style=\"margin:0\">
//                                         <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\"
//                                                type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"
//                                                width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\">
//                                         </embed>
//                                       </body>
//                                     </html>";

        NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = %0.0f\"/></head><body style=\"background:#FFF;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></object></div></body></html>";

        // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
//      NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

        NSLog(@"html:\n %@", youTubeVideoHTML);

        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, frame.size.width, frame.size.width, frame.size.height, urlString, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

        NSLog(@"html:\n %@", html);

        // Load the html into the webview
        [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please add details whether this happens in simulator or device, and on which system versions.

Comment: I can't simulate it in the simulator because youtube videos don't embed on the simulator. The issue is repeatable on my two devices, an original iPad and an iPad 2 running 5.1.1. I don't have any other iPads to test it on.

Comment: Alright. Didn't know that about the simulator! Sorry I probably won't be any help; I just wanted to make sure it's not just an issue in the simulator.

Comment: @fzwo all good, nor did I until I tried doing this. Thanks for reading the Q.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: I think I have, I'll post a solution this week for you if that'll be helpful. In the interim, just check that you have set a RootViewController; I think that solved the problem for me. I was just adding my primary view as a subview. When I upgraded to the iOS6 SDK it required a RootViewController for things to work properly; ensuring I had a RootViewController fixed the problem with the WebView. I haven't had a chance to test properly yet though so let me know how you get on.

Comment: Actually - scratch that. Problem is still happening. Time for a bounty.

Comment: Is webview or its container presented modally? Modally presented webview after playing embeded media content may crash, but its fixable.

Comment: Yes, the web view is in a modal ViewController.

Comment: a very minor glitch, but your html is missing a </head> .  it seems unlikely to me that this is the problem …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal view on iOS 5.0 and iOS 5.1 is the problem that causes crash on full screen video, AFAIK. They just changed hierarchy of views in that version of iOS (`parentViewController` and `presentingViewController`) and that is the aftermath. I asked about it long time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472959/uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-and-qiucktimeplugin) and one more same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905258/ios5-exception-on-uiwebview-in-modal-uiviewcontroller-playing-youtube-video) and still no one knows what to do.

First of all, they fixed it in 6.0, I guess, that's good.

For 5.1 we changed design a little and avoided modal view. Do it, if it is possible in your situation.

Comment: Ok. At this stage anything <ios6 shows a button to jump to a safari window with the link. Ios6 uptake seems pretty fast so that might be the best way for now.