# iOS APP - youtube video iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

App crashes when playing **youtube** video in fullscreen mode. 
It inside `UIWebView` which embedded in `viewController` presented modally on `rootViewController` of `window`.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi you can refer this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555502/youtube-embedded-in-uiwebview-causes-crash-on-ipad-when-entering-full-screen


Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of reputation I can not comment. Could you show us some code how you have done this.
I am doing it like this and it works fine for me with MoviePlayer:

```
NSString *youTubeURL = @"https://www.youtube.com/v/VCTen3-B8GU";

   NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
   [html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
   [html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
   [html appendString:@"body {"];
   [html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
   [html appendString:@"color: white;"];
   [html appendString:@"}"];
   [html appendString:@"</style>"];
   [html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
   [html appendFormat:@"<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"", youTubeURL];
   [html appendFormat:@"width=\"%0.0d\" height=\"%0.0d\"></embed>", 320, 200];
   [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

   [self.view loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```